# Hyphen in “fine-grained” when it follows a noun

Tags: adjectives, hyphens

There is the following sentence in the Chicago Manual of Style:

> When compound modifiers (also called phrasal adjectives) such as *open-mouthed* or *full-length* precede a noun, hyphenation usually lends clarity. … When such compounds follow the noun they modify, hyphenation is usually unnecessary, even for adjectival compounds that are hyphenated in Webster’s (such as *well-read* or *ill-humored*).

There is also the following one:

> If the phrasal adjective follows a verb, it is usually unhyphenated—for example, compare *a well-trained athlete* with *an athlete who is well trained*.

My question is: Does it apply to *fine-grained*? For instance, is the following correct?

> Such information is called *fine grained*, as it contains multiple measurements.

Or should it be instead as follows?

> Such information is called *fine-grained*, as it contains multiple measurements.

I suspect that *fine-grained* doesn’t qualify as a phrasal adjective.

Comment: "Well-trained" is a verb-centred compound adjective, just the same as "well-travelled, well-behaved etc. are. They should be hyphenated whether used attributively or postpositively. Fine-grained is also a compound adjective - in fact it's even lexicalised.

Comment: @BillJ, you mean _fine-grained_ should be spelled as _fine grained_ after nouns, right?

Comment: I would spell it as "fine-grained" both before and after nouns. [link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=It+is+fine-grained%2CIt+is+fine+grained&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=50&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CIt%20is%20fine%20-%20grained%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CIt%20is%20fine%20grained%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: These compounds tend to be hyphenated but a percentage or writers and/or editors do not hyphenate. This is ultimately a matter of style and typographic/orthographic convention.

Comment: If "fine-grained" is not hyphenated, it's not a compound, but a syntactic construction, which it isn't!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might use *fine grained* when used after the noun, and that's how I read the CMOS. I also agree with their overall philosophy of using  a minimum of hyphens, usually only to prevent ambiguity. I don't see any ambiguity in *The wood is fine grained*.

On the other hand  the CMOS also says to look up words in Webster’s dictionary to see how they are used. Nevertheless, just because something is spelled a particular way in a dictionary doesn't mean the spelling won't change.

So, it's ultimately a matter of style.

I  am  however not sure I would ever use 'fine grained' to refer to *information*. How does the definition of fine-grained fit with information? Note: As I look on Google books, I see *fine-grained information* used mostly in specific disciplines rather than general usage. I wasn't aware of this specialized usage.

Comment: Information can certainly be fine-grained. We talk of the fine-grained semantic classification of adjuncts, where it means in great detail.

Answer (score 2):

To paraphrase BillJ's comment:

"Fine-grained" is a compound adjective, composed of the two separate adjectives "fine" and "grained".  Other examples are "soft-spoken", "hard-edged", "steep-sided", and so on.

In contrast, "well-trained" is a "verb-centered" compound adjective composed of the *adverb* "well" and the adjective "trained".

Many compound adjectives *could* be written using the adverb -- "finely-grained", "softly-spoken", etc. -- but aren't by convention.

I tentatively agree that verb-centered compound adjectives don't have to be hyphenated when it follows a verb.

> The wood was **finely grained**, treated with protective oils and polished by generations of loving hands.

Otherwise compound adjectives should be hyphenated no matter where they appear in the sentence:

> The **hard-bitten** detective stared down the suspect.  "Where were you last night?!" he demanded.